# How to do a JPA Merge on a new object which has a foreign key entity coluimn as its primary key in a single transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got two classes. 
The first class has one field being a primary key column. 
The second class references this type as a OneToOne relationship, and uses this foreign key column as its own Primary key.

The tables and classes look like this:

### **IdTypeDescription**

```
itype_code      PK   FK (IdType.code)           
category    
name
```

### **IdType**

```
code    PK
```

**The classes**

```
@Entity
public class IdTypeDescription implements Serializable
{
    public IdTypeDescription()
    {
        /**
         * necessary default constructor for JPA
         */
    }

    public IdTypeDescription(IdCategory idCat, String idTypeCode, String idTypeName)
    {
        this.category = idCat;
        this.itype = new IdType(idTypeCode);
        this.name = idTypeName;
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public IdType itype;

    public IdCategory category;

    public String name;
}
```

**Id table class**

```
@Entity
public class IdType implements Serializable
{
    public IdType()
    {

    }
    public IdType(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }   

    @Id
    public String code;
}
```

I need to have the structure like this because I also want another class/table referring to the IdType table as well. However, I haven't got that far yet.

My problem is now that when attempting to merge a new object
(something which works when itype is a simple String and primary key)
instead of going through I get complaints from Hibernate about my primary key being null.

```
idTypeCode is:  Visit_number
idTypeName is:  visit id
idCategory is:  PATIENT
[error] - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - NULL not allowed for column "ITYPE_CODE"; SQL statement:
insert into IdTypeDescription (category, name, itype_code) values (?, ?, ?) [23502-187]
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:86)
```

I have tried persisting the objects in two ways:

```
IdType itype = (IdType) em.merge(idDescr.itype);
idDescr.itype = itype;
em.merge(idDescr);
```

and of course also tried simply:

```
em.merge(idDescr);
```

In fact, I get a similar problem when instead of a merge I try a persist.

I guessed the reason (but haven't found documentation for this) being that I needed to persist the child object first separately in its own transaction. Like so:

```
    JPA.withTransaction(() -> JPA.em().persist(idType.itype));
    JPA.withTransaction(() -> JPA.em().persist(idType));
```

That worked! However, I want to be able to do it in a single transaction!
Additionally, I need to do a merge, as I don't know if the object exists or not already in the database.

My attempt to try a similar strategy with the **merge failed:**

```
    try
    {
        JPA.withTransaction(() -> idType.itype = JPA.em().merge(idType.itype));
        JPA.withTransaction(() -> JPA.em().merge(idType));
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

even in doing a persist on the IdType and then a merge on the IdTypeDescriptor fails (at the merge. The persist works)

```
    try
    {
        JPA.withTransaction(() -> JPA.em().persist(idType.itype));
        JPA.withTransaction(() -> JPA.em().merge(idType));
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, what do I have to do to get this working ? 
Is it possible?

If not, how do other people deal with objects that use purely natural primary keys only, and have no handy artificial key's existence to check for (to decide if to persist or merge).

Oh, and, before someone suggests it, I can't have a reference to the IdTypeDescriptor in the IdType. Or at least, for reasons of the actual Object design, I was trying to avoid that.

Anyone?

Comment: Not sure I got your question completely.But to simplify, I think your requirement is you have two entities that have onetoone mapping with a shared PK and also a FK relationship. If so, u may want to check `@MapsId` annotation that helps.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu  Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't seem to help. I have a feeling that I need to have the association explicit on both sides. In fact, I suspect the guys at Grails were having that same problem some time ago: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8337     I will try doing that change ... just to see if that fixes the problem